# problemas nombre dinamico evento clic dentro de un For no funciona jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Saludos al asignar un nombre dinámico no se asigna la acción

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="section no-pad-bot" id="index-banner">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12">
          <div id="crad0"> Presiona 1</div>
          <div id="crad1"> Presiona 2</div>
          <div id="crad2"> Presiona 3</div>
          <div id="crad3"> Presiona 4</div>
          <div id="crad4"> Presiona 5</div>
          <div id="crad5"> Presiona 6</div>
          <div id="crad6"> Presiona 7</div>
          <div id="crad7"> Presiona 8</div>
          <div id="crad8"> Presiona 9</div>
          <div id="crad9"> Presiona 10</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.js"></script>
    <script>

        for(var i = 0 ; i <10; ++i)
        {
        $("#crad"+i).click(function() { console.log("mensaje: "+i) });
        }  

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Puede agregar su HTML?

Comment: Hola Fabian, para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida en la comunidad debes agregar más código que estés usando, por ejm el HTML, te invito a que leas [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y también [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), saludos !

Comment: Saludos ya integre el codigo html

Comment: Genial, ahora dinos cual es tu problema exacto ? te sale algún error? como se comporta tu código

Comment: Saludos Camilo, lo que sucede es que al presionar cada uno de los elementos no se ejecuta la acción  de mandar un mensaje a la consola, no hay ningún mensaje de error

Comment: Acabo de correrlo en un archivo local mio y funciona correctamente, con la observación de que siempre imprime el numero 10 con obvia razón

Comment: Para que imprima el valor de `i` que quieres registrar a cada click, puedes usar `bind()` para que no te imprima siempre el valor final de `i` que es como lo tienes en tu código.

Comment: @Lixus muchas gracias el utilizar bind() me fue de mucha ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu ejemplo function el problema es que siempre te toma el último valor por temas de como maneja el [event loop o bucle de eventos de Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

Posibles soluciones, usar IFFY que es tan solo crear una clausura javascript para crear diferentes scopes en la ejecución del for:

```
  for(var i = 0 ; i <10; ++i)
    {
        (function(i){
            $("#crad"+i).click(function() { console.log("mensaje: "+i) });
        })(i)
    }
```

Otra solución es usar let, en vez de bar dentro del for:

```
for(let i = 0 ; i <10; ++i)
{
$("#crad"+i).click(function() { console.log("mensaje: "+i) });
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Wilfredo

Comment: @FabianVazquezGomez de nada, te agregué el link que explica el bucle de evento de javascript, es un enlace que te lleva a un articulo de mozilla, es algo facíl de entender y es como funciona JS. si no entiendes algo explico mas detallada la respuesta.